# Orders view personalization

Tags: views, commerce

Apache 2.4.29 + php8.1 + mySQL 5.7.41
Drupal 9.5.3
Commerce 8.x-2.33

Hi all folks !
I'm trying to personalize the orders view with custumer's name, adress, ...
To do that i add the "commande" field in the view with "rendered entity" form, but with that i see all the command's history, commentaries ... despite the fact that i create un special "listing" display format for commands and  i hide every fields.
The "listing" selection appears good in the field format in the view.
Need some help, please.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The question seems rather unclear and could do with screenshots and more of an explanation of what the end result should be.

However, if you are trying to attach a different entity to a view to display its fields it sounds like you would be better off adding a relationship to the view of this "Commande" entity. This can be found under the Advanced section on the right side of the Views edit screen.
Once you have the correct relationship, you will find additional fields can be added. Without knowing more about your site I can't tell you more than that, but that should be a good starting point for you.

If you still can't find a solution via views, you may need to look at creating a custom module and creating your own controller to display the table you need.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your rapid answers !
You're right sorry. I need to display in the goal of commands preparation, all the informations of the commands in a listing display :
- n° of command (no problem for that, great !),
- email of the customer (no problem for that, great !),
- elts of the commands (no problem for that, great !),
...
...
- name of the customer (which is enter in the checkout),
- address of the customer (idem). Because without that i only get the "User/Customer" info (login+email). So to do that i try to modify the view (admin/commerce/orders) :
I add the "Rendered entity"